# O que significa "mas que"?

Tags: significado, significado-em-contexto

O que significa **mas que**?

Por exemplo:

> Ele disse que estava cansado porque tinha trabalhado muito naquele dia, mas que trabalharia menos no dia seguinte.

Eu procurei na internet mas não achei uma resposta certa por isso.

Comment: Você entende a frase ou não? Acho poco acreditável você fazer uma pergunta em bom português sem entender aquela frase.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mas: conjunção adversativa

Que: conjunção subordinativa integrante, introduz uma oração (subordinada substantiva) após outra (oração principal).

Ele disse que [...], mas ((também) disse) que trabalharia menos.

O `‘mas’` explicita a antítese (oposição de ideias), o `‘que’` retoma a ação ‘dizer’.

Para esclarecer: o verbo (dizer) pede complemento (nesse caso, direto), esse complemento pode ser um **substantivo** ou **pronome**, como em:

> Ele disse **as instruções**/Ele disse **tudo**.

Porém também pode ser uma **oração**:

> Ele disse **que queria jogar futebol**.

Nessa sua construção, o ‘disse’ possui 2 complementos (o que é muito bem possível: `Ele disse tudo e as instruções.`), complementos oracionais, os quais em sua forma desenvolvida — em oposição à reduzida — pedem o vocábulo “que”. Portanto:

**Ele**[*sujeito*] **disse**[*verbo*] {**que estava cansado porque havia trabalhado muito naquele dia**}[tudo bem que existem duas orações aqui, mas tudo isso é ainda *COMPLEMENTO 1 do verbo “disse”*], **mas**[*conjunção* indicando que as duas orações conectadas representam ideias supostamente opostas] {**que trabalharia menos no dia seguinte**}[*complemento 2*].

Equivalente ao inglês:

> He said **that** [...], **but** (also) **that** he would work...

Comment: Obrigado William!

Comment: O inglês é necessário?

Comment: @Majid Corrigi o 'Portanto:'. A legenda do 'mas' estava erroneamente como '... supostamente compostas', o correto agora está '... supostamente opostas'.